# Automatically create directories from long paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-io, create-directory

I have a collection of files with fully qualified paths (root/test/thing1/thing2/file.txt).  I want to `foreach` over this collection and drop the file into the location defined in the path, however, if certain directories don't exist, I want them to great created automatically.  My program has a default "drop location", such as `z:/`.  The "drop location" starts off empty, so in my example above, the first item should automatically create the directories needed to create `z:/root/test/thing1/thing2/file.txt`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
foreach (var relativePath in files.Keys)
{
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(defaultLocation, relativePath);
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);

    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    saveFile(fullPath, files[relativePath]);
}
```

where files is `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 18):

```
string somepath = @"z:/root/test/thing1/thing2/file.txt";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( ( somepath ) );
```

Comment: The create Directory.CreateDirectory(somepath) method creates all directories and subdirectories for you

Answer (score 8):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("/root/...")
```

Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path

Comment: Agreed, no need to check if directory exists as it does this internally.

Answer (score 4):

Check [IO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) ([Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx), [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)), I think they'll help you

```
using System.IO
```

Then check it..

```
string fileName =@"d:/root/test/thing1/thing2/file.txt"; 
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string filename = "c:\\temp\\wibble\\wobble\\file.txt";
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
}
File.Create(filename);
```

with suitable exception handling, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've found setting the "default location" at the start of execution to be helpful and reduce a bit of redundant code (e.g., `Path.Combine(defaultLocation, relativePath)`).

Example:

```
var defaultLocation = "z:/";
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(defaultLocation);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
```